# How to left-normalize a Matrix Product State

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, tensor-network

If you are reading this, you should probably have some background in Tensor Networks or Matrix Products States or this will be insufficient information.

So when putting a MPS into left (or right) canonical form, we can do this with a Single Value Decomposition, or easier, a QR decomposition. Now I am following this procedure in several papers but I don't seem to grasp it completely.

On page 43 of this paper the procedure is explained properly (using SVD instead of QR): https://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.3477.pdf

[image]

Or on page 7 of this paper if it's unclear: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.05824.pdf

For each lattice site of the TN (rank 3-tensor) it comes down to taking the left bond index (dim = χ) and the physical index (dim = d) and grouping this together, creating a matrix of dimension of $(d * χ) \times (χ)$.

Then we need to take the QR decomposition of this "grouped matrix", which actually originated from a rank 3-tensor. (In the picture they do an SVD but QR works as fine if you just multiply the last two matrices of the SVD into one matrix you have the same structure as QR). Q will be unitary and have dimension $(d * χ) \times (d*χ)$, and R will have dimension $(d * χ) \times (χ)$. Everything good so far. Focusing on Q, now we have to split the indices back again into the physical index and the bond dimension to regain the normalized matrices at the lattice site. But now we have $(d * χ) \times (d*χ)$ and need to split it back again in $(d * χ) \times (χ)$ or $d \times \chi \times \chi$ (which was the original dimension of the grouped matrix). We have more elements than we began with, how do we solve this? Or where is the fault in my reasoning.

Comment: Can you work on the formatting & self-containedness of your question?  Or do you expect people to go through two papers to understand your question?  (I mean, the paragraph which actually contains your question is a paragraph with no formatting whatsoever - consider breaking it up in several paragraph etc.  Also, it would help if you would put the matrices you talk about into context.)

Comment: Oh, and: DON'T LINK TO PDFs!

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, but I can't be explaining the whole concept of tensor networks/MPS here because that would be a lot of work. I tried to put the referenced summation over the matrices here in an image. I'll try to break up my question. Thanks

Comment: That's not what I mean: But if you want the attention of MPS experts, it might nevertheless help to serve the question to them in a digestible way, without them having to look up things in paper.  ---  And this is more than just adding a screenshot from the paper.  There is still this huge chunk of text without structure which is hard to parse!  ---  Note that this also makes both the question and answer of much less value to future readers, which makes it much less attractive to answer it carefully.

Comment: And, dude: You ***again*** linked to a PDF, after I edited those links!  This is deprecated for many reasons (there's meta posts about that).

Comment: You must have editied it while I was editing at the same time. I'm sorry!

Comment: If you edited at the same time, it seems puzzling that the tag edits are still there.  In any case, why don't you update the links to the abstract pages? They are still pointing to the PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do a "parsimonious" QR decomposition, where R is a square matrix and Q an isometry. (Differently speaking, remove the zero rows of R and the corresponding columns of Q.)

Then Q has dimension $d\chi\times\chi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is indeed what had to be done. I just found out!